# Get title from a div when another element is over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get the title of a div and insert it into a label with fixed position when the label is above the div. When I scroll down, the text in the label would change depending on the title of the div it is currently over.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I've tried the following, which makes me able to change the value of my label when it gets above the top of the div, which is what i want. The problem is that I'm using several divs using the same classname, so I need to get the title from the div I'm currently over...

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
   var fixed = $("div.fixed");

   var fixed_position = $("div.fixed").offset().top;
    var fixed_height = $("div.fixed").height();

   var toCross_position = $(".div-to-cross").offset().top;
   var toCross_height = $(".div-to-cross").height();

   if (fixed_position + fixed_height  < toCross_position) {
   fixed.text("");
   } else if (fixed_position > toCross_position + toCross_height) {
   fixed.text("");
   } else {
   fixed.text("");;
   }

 });
```

Comment: We would need to see the html/code you have and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please paste the code you tried!

Comment: Basicly you have a onScroll event to listen to, then compare pageOffset with scrollOffset, ...

Comment: Added a code snippet.

Comment: Yes, but how do I use the ids or indexes? That's the part that I need help with.

Comment: Please, could you add also your html or, better, a snippet here in SO?